# Python, sample larger than population

Tags: python

Ok this is something weird, I'm tring to write a scrip with the purpose of learning python, I'm stuck at this error, here is the code:

```
def get_segment(_len,dic):    
    word_segment = ''
    dictionary = []

    while dic > 0:
        if dic >= 8:            
            dictionary.append(DICTIONARY_SYMBOLS)
            dic -= 8            
        elif dic >= 4:
            dictionary.append(DICTIONARY_NUMBERS_DEC)
            dic -= 4
        elif dic >= 2:
            dictionary.append(DICTIONARY_LETTERS_LOWER)
            dic -= 2
        else:
            dictionary.append(DICTIONARY_LETTERS_UPPER)
            dic -= 1

    dictionary = scramble_list(dictionary)
    word_segment = ''.join(random.sample(dictionary,_len))

    return word_segment
```

The error is exactly `ValueError: Sample larger than population or is negative` but my list `dictionary` contains a lot more of elements than `_len` value, also considering that `_len` can be filled with repeated elements.

**edit**: I found the bug finally, I was appending not merging lists, replaced with `+=` and it is working fine now :)

Comment: You really shouldn't use `len` as a variable name, as it overrides a builtin method.

Comment: Also can you show an input that your function fails on?

Comment: what is `scramble_list`?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. `len` is almost certainly greater than the size of the dictionary as the error says. Rename `len` to `length` or something and then try `print(length, len(dictionary))` (that's `len` as in the built in function).

Comment: Just a side note: almost every case where you are using `while` in Python and it is not `while True` probably should be a `for` or list comprehension.

Comment: As a side note, your "dictionary" is actually list, not a dictionary.

Comment: I don't see how this is a duplicate of the cited question.  I believe the answer to your problem is you used `append()` when you should have used `extend()`.  By using `append()` your population is never more than the number of clauses in your `if` statement (i.e. four lists in a list) but by using `extend()` your population is based on the length of the various `DICTIONARY_*` lists.